# BeanDefinitionOverrideException, Spring Data JPA and JDBC beans conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jdbc

I planned to use **Spring Data JPA and JDBC** repositories in one application (some entities JPA and other JDBC) with **Spring Boot 2.1.7**.

```
public interface UserRepository2 extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "userstab")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    ...
}
```

Running application I got the error:

```
The bean 'userRepository2', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting **spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true**

Invalid bean definition with name 'userRepository2' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.**jpa**.repository.support.**JpaRepositoryFactoryBean**]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'userRepository2': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.**jdbc**.repository.support.**JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean**];
```

I tried Spring Boot test-application without Spring Data JDBC **=> no problems**

I tried this application with spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true  **=> no problems**

So Spring Data creates **2 repository beans (JPA and JDBC) from one repository interface** with the name of interface (userRepository2).
I can't set different names for this 2 repo beans, can't use spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true.

**What are the best practices for choosing JPA/JDBC for every repository/entity?**

PS: found `@EnableJdbcRepositories` with basePackages property, but i am not sure that it is a good idea

Comment: Please provide more info, esp. the Repository class for user Data JPA, and Data Jdbc and the Entity class.

Comment: Repository classes are automatically generated by Spring Data

Comment: I have tried to use 4 repos(JPA, Data JPA, Jdbc, Data Jdbc) in a single app, it works, check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/tree/master/jdbc-ds-vanilla/src/main/java/com/example/demo), [4 urls to test them](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/blob/master/jdbc-ds-vanilla/src/main/java/com/example/demo/WebConfig.java#L46).

Comment: i suppose that this is the reason, why your repositories beans aren't in conflict:   @EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.jdbc")

Comment: It is not related. Remove it and it still works.

Comment: So how it works? Explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to a fixed bug in older versions of Spring Data JDBC. Make sure that you have at least one of the following versions of `spring-data-jdbc`

1.0.12
1.1.1
2.0.0

See [DATAJDBC-437](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-437) for details.